# Validity of the proof $\mathbb R$ is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, real-numbers

My attempt: take the interval $H=(0,1)$. Assume $(0,1)$ is countable, then there exist a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $H$ where. Define elements of $H$ as a monotonically increasing sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ , $H=\{a_i | i \in\mathbb  N\}$. However $a_1^{2} \in (0,1)$ and is not an element of $H$ since $a_1^{2}<a_1$. Thus $H \neq (0,1)$ which is a contradiction. Hence $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

Is my attempt valid?

Comment: The problem is that you assume that exists a bijection that is also an increasing sequence. For example, I know that exists a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$, but from this I can not assume that exists an bijection that is also continuos.

Comment: Hint: Uses the Nested Interval Theorem.

Comment: You have successfully proven that there is no **monotone increasing** surjection from $\Bbb{N}$ to $(0, 1)$. The monotone increasing assumption cannot be easily removed from this argument, so you've proven something substantially weaker than $(0, 1)$ being uncountable.

Comment: Consider $K:=(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q.$ As far as I can see you can use the same argument to "prove" that $K$ is uncountable. But $K$ certainly is countable.

Comment: For that matter, the argument would "prove" that $\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}$ is not countable. The fundamental mental stumbling block, probably, is that cardinality (including countability) has nothing to do with any other properties we associate with special sets, such as ordering (inequalities), or even the existence of multiplication/squaring in the first place. Set cardinality is about bare sets, not sets with additional structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just gathering up the several apt comments: there is simply no assurance, no general reason, why a countable subset of $(0,1)$ (etc.) should occur as a monotone increasing sequence. The comments give counter-examples: $\{1,{1\over 2},{1\over 3},\ldots\}$ and, actually, all rationals in that interval. Trying "either monotone increasing sequence or monotone decreasing sequence" also is false: the rationals in the interval.

In fact, the question of "what countable (total) order types are there?" is not trivially answerable, I think. :)